# Column headers are recurring in the CSV or XLS export in Jasper Reports when using the "Table Element"

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-csv

The column headers are recurring when a csv or xls import is done in the jasper reports. This is if we are using a "Table Element" in the report. I have figured out the way to exclude the column headers if the Table element is not used . I have used the following lines properties to do so

`

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.3" value="columnHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.3" value="*"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.4" value="columnFooter"/>`
```

But the problem persists if I am using a Table element.
I have added the property to the table properties and tried but it seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

For XLSx, To prevent the column headers to be recurring from table element, try setting the below three parameters and run the report.

net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.report.myreport=YOUR_REPORT_NAME
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.myreport=columnHeader
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.myreport=*

NOTE: replace the report name with actual value in the first property.